# smarty and date

Tags: smarty

i get date with: `{$smarty.now|date_format:'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'}`

But how get 20 day after?

If now: `2010 05 05 12:12:12`, I wish to show `2010 25 05 12:12:12`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the `strtotime()` php function and assign your variable to smarty. Something like this:

```
<?php
$later = strtotime('+20 day');
$smarty->assign('later', $later);
?>
```

Then in the template:

```
{ $later|date_format:'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'}
```

Comment: Thanks, but i can't using PHP code. Maybe is decision with only Smarty?

Comment: There are now other answers which rely entirely on smarty and require no PHP code

Answer (score 19):

`{$smarty.now}` is a simple timestamp (number of seconds since 1970). So you can just add as many seconds to it as you need:

```
{$smarty.now+20*24*60*60|date_format:'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'} //+20 days
```

This works in Smarty3, if not in older versions then you might need to do the math with `{assign}` and/or `{math}` directives.

Answer (score 8):

You can use strtotime() directly as a modifier.

```
{"+20 days"|strtotime|date_format:"Y/m/d"}
```

Answer (score 3):

In newer versions of smarty it will strtotime any string you prepend

I.e. instead of doing `{$smarty.now|date_format:'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'}` you can also do `{"now"|date_format:'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'}`

To get the date 20 days from now, you can do:

`{"+20 days"|date_format:"%Y-%m-%d"}`

Answer (score 0):

```
{assign var="iItemOne" value=$smarty.now}
{assign var="iItemTwo" value=1296000} //60*60*24*15-> for 15 days
{assign var="iSum" value=$iItemOne+$iItemTwo}

{$iSum|date_format:'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'}
```

Answer (score -1):

Tested in smarty : Add 1 day ,2 days ......365 days in dynamic date.

```
$one= date("Y-m-d", strtotime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime('$add dynamic date variable')) . " + 1 day"));
  $this->smarty->assign('one',$one);

$two= date("Y-m-d", strtotime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime('$add dynamic date variable')) . " + 2 day"));
  $this->smarty->assign('two',$two);
...
..

$oneyear= date("Y-m-d", strtotime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime('$add dynamic date variable')) . " + 365 day"));
  $this->smarty->assign('oneyear',$oneyear);
```